# dialyzer fails to recognise elixir functions with error :0:unknown_function

Tags: elixir, dialyzer, asdf-vm

I have elixir 1.7.2 on my computer installed using `asdf`, both elixir and erlang otp 21. On my project mix file I have added the latest release candidate of dialyzer as instructed on [dialyzer github](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir#changes-in-10)

```
{:dialyxir, "~> 1.0.0-rc.3", only: [:dev], runtime: false}
```

When I run `mix dialyzer` I get a couple of errors when its creating the plt among them being:

```
Could not get Core Erlang code for: /home/sigu/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.7.2/lib/elixir/ebin/elixir_parser.beam

Recompile with +debug_info or analyze starting from source code  Could not get Core Erlang code for: /home/sigu/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.7.2/lib/logger/ebin/Elixir.Logger.ErlangHandler.beam
```

Everything then fails with errors included the elixir built in functions like `System.get_env/1`

```
:0:unknown_function
Function System.get_env/1 does not exist.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the error is being caused by the fact that when I installed `elixir`, asdf uses a version precompiled with erlang otp-20. When dialyzer tries to create the plt, it fails to find elixir 1.7.2 compiled with otp-21.

To work around this, install elixir precompiled with otp-21 as instructed on the [asdf/elixir github](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-elixir#elixir-precompiled-versions) - Thanks to the elixir slack where I found the solution

```
asdf install elixir 1.7.2-otp-21
```

Command installs elixir precompiled with otp-21.

Everything should work as expected now

Comment: I'm getting the error about not finding the Erlang code, depsite having installed asdf with  
erlang 22.3.4
elixir 1.7.4-otp-22
I also deleted the old plts that were compiled with OTP21 and tried from scratch with the same problem. Any ideas?